# Will emptying a list release memory in Python?

Tags: python, memory-management

Will this release memory in Python?

```
a = range(200)
a = []
```

Or do I have to specifically do `del a`?

```
SPORTS = ['cricket', 'football']

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    logger = logging.getLogger('load_articles')
    for sport in self.SPORTS:
        logger.info('setting sport')
        self.sport = sport
        self.load_articles_in_mem() #this populates the array articles
        obj, created = self.create_sport()
        self.create_articles_for(obj)
        self.articles = []
    logger.info("Articles loaded in memory %s" % len(self.articles))
```

So here articles get loaded into memory from some source, and as I increase the `SPORTS` list I would keep bloating the `articles` list. I could just empty the list inside the loop once everything I need was done.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this ?

Comment: Why not simply create a huge list, note the RAM usage, run the next line and compare RAM usage?

Comment: You are not emptying a, you are creating a new list and binding the name a to it. The range(200) will be garbage collected (if there's no other reference to it).

Comment: So since I am creating a new list, the old reference gets GCed anyway. yeah ?

Answer (score 5):

I have just checked for Python2.6 and created `a = range(100000000)` it consumed up to `700 MB` of RAM. then `a = []` it consumed additional `600 MB` total of `1.3 GB of RAM`. Then `del a` and nothing changed. The memory was released after I closed Python console.

For Python 3.4 `range` will not create any list - so it will not consume much memory. I have run `a = range(1000000000000)` and barely something changed with memory consumption.
But then I have run `a = [x for x in range(10000000)]` and it consumed around `200 MB` then run `a = []` and memory was released. Again created `a = [x for x in range(10000000)]` and it took 200 MB and then `del a` and memory was released.

Conclusion:
Py26 does not garbage collect unused list. Same for Py27. (just checked)
Py34 will garbage collect unused list and release memory.

---

PS.
I have runned in Python2.6 same test as for Python3.4. And the result was the same like previous. The memory was **not** released.

Comment: I have also encountered the problem of Python2.7 not releasing memory of unused lists so this is how I found your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It *should* release memory, since there will be no references to the objects which where in list. But Python interpreter doesn't guarantee this, as far as I know.

Comment: `a = range(10**8), a = []` after this python.exe still hold 2,4 Gb memory. Some was released, but not everything. It was 3,2 Gb before reassigning a.

Comment: In python 3 it seems to release the memory though

Comment: I believe there should be no difference between ```a = []``` and ```del a```. If memory is still not freed, you can try to force garbage collection, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html